# Нужно написать программу для файла

Tags: c++, строки, visual-studio, файлы, visual-c++

Нужно написать программу, которая считывает строки с файла и записывает их в исходный файл в перевернутом виде и в обратном порядке. Я сделал, что строчки пишет задом наперед, но не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы порядок был обратным. Помогите)

Вот код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream f("f.txt");
    ofstream g("g.txt");
    string s;
    char c;
    while (getline(f, s))
    {
        reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        g << s << endl;
    }
    g.close();
    f.close();

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Простейший способ - засунуть их в массив (вектор), а потом забирать с конца.

Comment: @Harry память надо. А нельзя просто курсор в начало файла переставлять?

Comment: Да можно и вообще переворачивать не строчки, а сразу весь файл. Как раз и получился то, что требуется.

Comment: можете написать это в коде, а то я не очень понимаю всю эту тему с файлами?)

Comment: Ну, вариант такой - выделяем буфер сколько не жалко, идем на конец файла, отступаем на размер буфера, читаем, выводим в обратном порядке. Отступаем на 2 буфера, читаем, выводим... Ну и так далее, до начала - если выскочит смещение в меньше нуля - то читать меньше и начиная с нулевой позиции...

Comment: можете написать код?)

Comment: в перевернутом виде и в обратном порядке. ???? это типо отзеркалить память с хвостика*?

Comment: Если небольшой - просто втяните полностью в память и идите задом наперед, нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю вариант, где  стандартные алгоритмы не нужны. Достаточно включать следующие файлы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
```

Строки в перевернутом виде складываем в стек, а потом оттуда записываем в файл, вытаскивая из стека(последняя будет первой), пока стек не пустой:

```
ifstream f("f.txt");
ofstream g("g.txt");
std::stack<string>  ss;      
string s;
while (getline(f, s))
{
    ss.push(string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()));
}
while (!ss.empty()) {
    g << ss.top();
    ss.pop();
}

g.close();
f.close();
```

Comment: А если файл размером в гигабайты?...

Comment: обработать по частям ведь тоже можно. Не думаю, что такая задача будет иметь практическое применение, поэтому не интересно обсуждать.

Answer (score 0):

Этот код можно использовать как пример. По большей степени это аналог работы с векторами так что думаю ни чего сложного

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream f("f.txt");
    ofstream g("g.txt");
    string s;

    while (f)
    {
        string s;
        getline(f, s);
        string end;
        if (s.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // начинаем отсчет с конца 
                end.push_back(s[i]); // как и в векторах в строках есть функция push_back()

            }
        }
        g << end << '\n';

    }
    g.close();
    f.close();

    system("pause");
}
```

Результат работы я полагаю соответствует заданию
[image: Результаты]

Comment: _записывает их в исходный файл в перевернутом виде **и в обратном порядке**_

Comment: ой, не заметил, но ни чего, можно перезаписать созданный файл в исходный при этом удалив переходной (если автору задания потребуется доделанная реализация, а не просто система переворота строк то готов закончить)

Comment: да, нужно в обратном порядке
если вам не сложно, то можете дописать? буду очень признателен)))